# Test if a layout has been "inflated"

Tags: android, android-layout, swipe

I have an android Activity with swipe navigation (implemented with ViewPager).

```
public class UberActivity extends FragmentActivity {

ViewPager mViewPager;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //... some stuff

        myfragment1=new MyFragment1();
        myfragment2=new MyFragment2();
        myfragment3=new MyFragment3();
        myfragment4=new MyFragment4();
    }

public void onChoiceSelected(){
    mViewPager.post(new Runnable(){public void run(){
        myfragmen1.update();
        myfragmen2.update();
        myfragmen3.update();
        myfragmen4.update();
    }});
}
}

public class Fragment4 extends Fragment {
View v;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater layoutInflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout,container,false);
        return v;
}         
public void update(){
    ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText("new text");
}
```

I will get a NullPointerException on update(), unless I beforehand swipe to it (so that its layout is actually inflated before calling update()).
The problem here is that Fragment4 is instanced but its OnCreateView() is not called. How should I check if OnCreateView() is called? I could put a boolean there, but I don't think this is a best practice...

Comment: it is possible to do that ?

 
if(v!=null && v.findViewById(R.id.textView1)!=null)  
   ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText("new text");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add an if-statement around 'v', checking if it is null or not.

```
public void update(){
    if (v != null) {
        ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText("new text");
    }
}
```